# Dropdown inside Input field

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, jquery-ui

I like to do this kind of search box by using HTML and CSS. I used Jquery UI autocomplete category widget, It doesnt worked out.
Please help me to do this, share any demo links if you have.[image: search bar having dropdown]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use Select2, and customize it to your liking.

https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

check below link .   jquery-ui is solve the problem. other wise provide  fiddle for this.

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: yes i used that.. but inside how to use dropdown submenu?